# ACCESS SQL IIf Statement doesn't include SUM

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, conditional-statements, iif

I've an IIf-Statement as a new Column *Vergleich*, which should compare the column *Summe_Teile_SAB* and *Import_Einzelstueckliste.Bedarfsmenge*. But I can't include the column *Summe_Teile_SAB* in the IIf statement as this column is a SUM() within the SELECT *SUM(SAB_Teile.Anzahl) AS Summe_Teile_SAB*.
Therefore it doesn't compare the numbers of the *Teilenummer* from *Import_Einzelstueckliste.Bedarfsmenge* with the sum of the same *Teilenummer* from *SAB_Teile.Anzahl*.

| Erstentnahme | Teilenummer | Summe_Teile_SAB | Bedarfsmenge | Vergleich |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | 1308713 | 1 | 1 |  |
| E | 1308715 | 2 | 2 |  |
| E | 1309059 | 4 | 4 | Differenz |
| E | 1309061 | 1 | 1 |  |

```
INSERT INTO Import_Einzelstueckliste ( Teilenummer, Teilenummer, Teilenummer, Teilenummer, Teilenummer, Teilenummer )
SELECT SAB_Teile.Erstentnahme, SAB_Teile.Teilenummer, SAB_Teile.Bezeichnung, SUM(SAB_Teile.Anzahl) AS Summe_Teile_SAB, Import_Einzelstueckliste.Bedarfsmenge, IIf([SAB_Teile.Anzahl]=[Import_Einzelstueckliste.Bedarfsmenge],"","Differenz") AS Vergleich
FROM Import_Einzelstueckliste INNER JOIN SAB_Teile ON Import_Einzelstueckliste.Teilenummer = SAB_Teile.Teilenummer
GROUP BY SAB_Teile.Erstentnahme, SAB_Teile.Teilenummer, SAB_Teile.Bezeichnung, Import_Einzelstueckliste.Bedarfsmenge,  IIf([SAB_Teile.Anzahl]=[Import_Einzelstueckliste.Bedarfsmenge],"","Differenz")
HAVING (((SAB_Teile.Erstentnahme) Like "E") AND ((SAB_Teile.Teilenummer)<>""))
ORDER BY SAB_Teile.Teilenummer;
```

I expected by changing the first condition of the IIf statement *SAB_Teile.Anzahl* to *SAB_Teile.Summe_Teile_SAB* it would work, but it didn't .

Comment: Post data and code as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @June7 It would be consistent, if you would add a link, where someone could find instructions how to add tables and code as formatted text, according to "add details and clarify the problem to help others" - not just writing it down, like you objected to me ^^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code, https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: You're probably going to need a nested INNER JOIN where you calculate the sum, then join it back to Import_Einzelstueckliste

Comment: @June7 Please reopen the Question. I found a solution, so I could write it down and this question can be classed as "solved".

Comment: Should probably edit question to show sample raw data as well as desired result.

Comment: @June7 Again inconsistent behavior: You closed the questions with the charge of posting data and code as formatted text (although there are a lot of questions here on stackflow, which do not fulfill those specifications - means this is not an obligation here, maybe your personal rules). Now you are changing your rules to include new information. As I fulfilled your first (personal) restriction, be consistent and fair and open the question!

Comment: Closing and opening is not solely my decision, it is a group decision as you can see from the advisories. Took 3 votes to close and will need 3 votes to open. I already voted to reopen although you have not provided sample raw data, you provided result of a query. Following FAQ states when images are not appropriate https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Yes, a lot of people don't comply and are not corrected. JohnnyBones comment has suggestion that is probably correct approach.

Comment: Have you even reviewed any of the FAQ's? https://stackoverflow.com/help